# strange syntax in lambda expression

Tags: scala

```
val (xa, xb) = xs partition ( a > )
```

What is `a >` in above code and how is it different from `a > _`? (assume `a` is some predefined value)

Comment: yiack, this is what I don't like in scala :(

Comment: This syntax didn't use to be all that common in Scala, imho. It seems to be getting more popular of late -- and I include myself there. It looks a lot like Haskell, though, where this would be pretty standard.

Comment: @OscarRyz: What do you not like? Reduced syntactic clutter, or powerful type inference?

Comment: @Missiong Faktor. Unexpected black  magic. I wouldn't be surprised if tomorrow someone says: `xs partition -`  does the same or  `partition _xs` or   `a xs pttin` or whatever, because when I think I know a bit of Scala, a new idiom comes and change it all.  In the search for power, Scala is supporting pretty much any syntax that comes in the way.  That's what I don't quite like from it, I found it rather inconsistent. I **know** you think different, and that's ok.

Answer (score 11):

Any method that expects a function with some argument can be instead passed a one-argument method and, if the types work out, the method will be automatically converted.

So these all are valid:

```
class C { def go(i: Int) = -i }
val c = new C
List(1,2,3).foreach( println )
List(1,2,3).map( c go )
```

So, either `a` has the method `>` defined, or it can be implicitly converted to something with a `>` method.  For example, this works:

```
List(1,2,3).partition(2 >)
```

because (EDIT: one would *think* this would be true....) there is an implicit conversion from `Int` to `RichInt` (the same one that gives you `.toFloat` and such), and `RichInt` has a `>` method defined.  `partition` expects a function that takes `Int` and returns `Boolean` and `2 >` is a method that takes `Int` and returns `Boolean`.  So the conversion happens automatically.

(EDIT: but as @Lukas Rytz points out, it's even more tricky than that, because the compiler realizes that it can treat primitive ints specially, so even though `>` is not really a method on the object `2`, because `2` is not an object, and primitives do not have methods, the compiler recognizes that deferring to `RichInt` would be slower.  So, in fact, it just writes a method with the correct bytecode.)

Only if the correct conversion does not happen automatically (because of ambiguity, for example, or because you want to assign it to a variable) do you need to use `_` to create a function out of a method.  (And then it is not always exactly clear whether you are using `_` to convert from method to function, or using `_` as a placeholder for the input; fortunately, the result is the same either way.)

Comment: That's not entirely correct, there is no implicit conversion. The `Int` class has a `>` member (and also a `toFloat` in fact). The example after typing is `immutable.this.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3).partition({ ((x$1: Int) => 2.>(x$1)) });`.

Comment: @Lukas - Indeed--there goes compiler magic tricking me again.  Because, of course, `Int` isn't a real class.

Comment: For the scala compiler, `Int` is a real class with real methods (e.g. `>`), the special case is that the backend generates bytecode to use primitive operations instead of generating a method call. The fact that there are no source files for value classes is historical, and recently there was an attempt to change this, see http://github.com/soundrabbit/scala/commit/c13c67dda7c96c290d76a9b8763e559493704b9d. This might eventually make it into trunk.

Comment: @Lukas - I didn't mean that the Scala compiler didn't internally use a class to keep track of what was going on with Int, just that to the coder and to the bytecode `2` is not a class.  Try doing `2.getClass`, for example.  The list of problems on the attempt to change to using source code also highlights how specially primitives are treated.

Comment: that's right, value types are not class types. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

It is not different at all, it's just a shorter version.

```
scala> val a = 10
a: Int = 10

scala> val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

scala> val (xa, xb) = xs partition ( a > )
xa: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
xb: List[Int] = List(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is actually exactly the same.